# How to sort time ( In AM / PM ) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing problem with sorting according to AM / PM.

Here is my table data

```
login_time
1:30 PM
2:00 AM
8:00 AM
9:30 PM
10:00 PM
11:10 AM
```

I want result as:

```
login_time
2:00 AM
8:00 AM
11:10 AM
1:30 PM
9:30 PM
10:00 PM
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are those strings in your database?

Comment: yes , datatype is varchar(1024)

Comment: where is your query?  You can't sort data from a database without a query telling it to `order by login_time`

Comment: Well fix that! Use the appropriate datatype for your database and you can use order by.

Comment: you need to convert it to a datetime

Comment: In what universe is it at all sane to have a column that's meant to store a time declared as a varchar of up to **1024** characters?

Comment: @ManojPrajapat is the DB out of your control? Who the hell created a varchar(1024) to store a time? If you can, make that a `time` field (if using SQL Server 2008+).

Comment: I am using my sql.
Is this possible using `time` data type 
Actually data import from xml and in this format 12: AM

Comment: @ManojPrajapat convert it to time and then do what you need with it, store it, sort it

Comment: @ManojPrajapat I would push to change the type of the column as well. Since comments are not suitable to explain "complex" manipulations, I posted an answer below to show you the various step needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, and you could also extract only the time part with [TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) if you wish:

```
SELECT
  login_time
FROM
  tablename
ORDER BY
  STR_TO_DATE(login_time, '%l:%i %p')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/624d6/1).

Comment: This is working but is highly inefficient since you cannot build index on functions.

Answer (score 5):

If you already have your date as a `VARCHAR`, I suggest you to refactor that to a `TIME` column. This could be easily done online:

```
UPDATE tablename SET login_time = STR_TO_DATE(login_time, '%l:%i %p');
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE login_time login_time TIME;
```

I use the type `TIME` here since your data *apparently* only contains *time*. Maybe a `DATETIME` type would be most appropriate. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html for the various options.

Anyway, once the column has be refactored to the appropriate type, you could write:

```
SELECT
  login_time
FROM
  tablename
ORDER BY
  login_time
```

With the added benefit that *now* you can build an index on `login_time` to speedup your search/sort:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX ( login_time );
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03991/1 (click on 'View Execution Plan' to see that the actual index has been used).

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiple expressions in your ORDER BY clause to sort by the AM/PM first, 12th hour special case second, the Hour third, and tiebreak on minutes for the rest.

```
ORDER BY
  RIGHT(login_time, 2),
  CASE
    WHEN 12 = convert(int, REPLACE(LEFT(login_time, 2), ':', '')) THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END,
  convert(int, REPLACE(LEFT(login_time, 2), ':', '')),
  login_time
```

Comment: Are sure this would work? Have you tested this? It's definitely not as if the AM/PM format was sorting-friendly at all unless you really *make* it sort (with messier string expressions than yours). I mean, if you have 11 AM, 12 PM and 11 PM, your suggestion will not sort them the way they should be sorted.

Comment: here is my query with your order
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_data
ORDER BY RIGHT( login_time, 2 ) , CONVERT( INT, REPLACE( LEFT( login_time, 2 ) ,  ':',  '' ) ) , login_time
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: @AndriyM After the first expression, 11 AM would be first, 12 PM and 11 PM would be tied for second.  After the second expression, the tie would be broken - 11 PM would be second and 12 PM would be third.  But due to the nature of the 12 hour clock, 12 PM should be most firstest, so I will correct.

Comment: Actually I can now see another workaround. Take your original suggestion and change the second criterion, the `convert(int, ...)`, to `convert(int, ...) % 12`. That would be substituting 12's with 0's and leaving the others unchanged. So, apparently I was exaggerating the issue (sorry) and a working solution could be only *slightly* messier. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like comments mentioned, if possible - change the data type of the column. If this is out of your control order by converted value:

```
select login_time from table order by CAST(login_time as datetime)
```

Comment: nice and simple answer... Thank You! ~~~~```$$$````~~~