# How to sort a table by time column in Mysql/Sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql 5

Table name is schedule.

departure_time data_type = varchar(20)

**query**

```
select * from schedules;
```

**Output:**

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+
| travel_date | departure_time | origin_id | destination_id | operator_id | status | available_seats |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+
| 2014-06-09  | 02:30 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              44 |
| 2014-06-09  | 09:30 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              14 |
| 2014-06-09  | 10:00 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              24 |
| 2014-06-09  | 12:30 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              23 |
| 2014-06-09  | 11:15 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              27 |
| 2014-06-09  | 09:30 PM       |       134 |            251 |           4 | Active |              24 |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+



SELECT * FROM schedules 
WHERE (travel_date ='2014-06-09' and origin_id ='134' 
and destination_id ='251' and operator_id not in (SELECT id FROM operators WHERE (status != 'Active')) and status ='Active' and available_seats > 0) 
ORDER BY departure_time ASC;
```

output:

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+
| travel_date | departure_time | origin_id | destination_id | operator_id | status | available_seats |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+
| 2014-06-09  | 02:30 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              44 |
| 2014-06-09  | 09:30 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              14 |
| 2014-06-09  | 09:30 PM       |       134 |            251 |           4 | Active |              24 |
| 2014-06-09  | 10:00 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              24 |
| 2014-06-09  | 11:15 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              27 |
| 2014-06-09  | 12:30 PM       |       134 |            251 |           2 | Active |              23 |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+
```

Here how to make this table order by departure_time asc

eg: departure_time should come like this:- 12:30 PM ,02:30 PM, 09:30 PM ,09:30 PM ,10:00 PM, 11:15 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your order by statement like this it will help

```
  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(timeField,'%h.%i%p');
```

Data Type TIME is for storing time data type - that means no AM/PM. Store the data in Your database in 24 hour format and format it to 12 hour format with am/pm in PHP or MySQL using one of these:

PHP:

```
$date = new DateTime($mysql_column['time']);
$date->format('h:i:s a');
```

or:

```
$date = date('h:i:s a', strtotime($mysql_column['time']));
or MySQL:
```

SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%h:%i:%s %p', time) FROM table;

Comment: departure_time should order is coming like this:- 2:30 PM ,09:30 PM, 10:00 PM ,12:30 PM , 11:15 PM .Wrong..It should come like :- 12:30 PM, 2:30 PM, 09:30 PM, 10:00 PM, 11:15 PM. Right..

Comment: In that case you need to change design.

Comment: ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(timeField,'%h:%i%p'); Is It Right ?

Comment: Piyush i am working on Ruby on Rails 4. i think in mysql it is working fine. once check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/624d6/1

Answer (score 0):

It's type is `varchar(20)` so it will be sorted as simple string.

Comment: So what i need to do for making it sortable.

Comment: @user3676578 you can convert `departure_time` as `time` column

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110000/how-to-sort-time-in-am-pm-in-sql..here check the **Sylvain Leroux** answer