# Sort time in MySQL with multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

### Introduction

I have a table of buses in MySQL and each bus has a few arrival timings. I need to sort the buses by the first arrival.

### Unsorted Table

```
+-------+-------------------------------+
|  bus  |             time              |
+-------+-------------------------------+
| Bus A | 8 a.m.<br/>9 a.m.             |
| Bus B | 12 p.m.<br/>1 p.m.<br/>2 p.m. |
| Bus C | 10 a.m.                       |
| Bus D | 9:30 a.m.                     |
+-------+-------------------------------+
```

### Sorted (Wrong)

```
+-------+-------------------------------+
|  bus  |             time              |
+-------+-------------------------------+
| Bus C | 10 a.m.                       |
| Bus B | 12 p.m.<br/>1 p.m.<br/>2 p.m. |
| Bus A | 8 a.m.<br/>9 a.m.             |
| Bus D | 9:30 a.m.                     |
+-------+-------------------------------+
```

### Sorted (Correct)

```
+-------+-------------------------------+
|  bus  |             time              |
+-------+-------------------------------+
| Bus A | 8 a.m.<br/>9 a.m.             |
| Bus D | 9:30 a.m.                     |
| Bus C | 10 a.m.                       |
| Bus B | 12 p.m.<br/>1 p.m.<br/>2 p.m. |
+-------+-------------------------------+
```

### Query

I've tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110000/how-to-sort-time-in-am-pm-in-sql), but it doesn't seem to work. It might be due to formatting issues -- "2:00 AM" vs "2:00 a.m.".

```
SELECT bus_timing
FROM buses
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(bus_timing, '%l:%i %p')
```

### Question

So, how can I sort these data according to the timings without changing the data at all?

Comment: which data type is time column ?

Comment: @scaisEdge varchar (50)

Comment: why are there nulls in your  bus column? This is not excel this is a database

Comment: You have null for bus  in you table or is only for this show in this question?  and what do you mean exactly for doesn't work .. error?  .. others?

Comment: Try with STR_TO_DATE(bus_timing, '%H:%i')

Comment: @e4c5 Oops, I've updated question

Comment: @scaisEdge It's actual stored as `<br/>` in the database. The results aren't sorted properly, they are jumbled up.

Comment: your data is still wrong. The times shouldn't be in a single column separated by line breaks. In fact they shouldn't be in a single column at all

Comment: Inside you time column you have a stringh with  list of time ?  you should normalize your data correctly ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I've stored it as varchar(50), and the time column uses `<br/>` so that when the results are echoed in PHP, they will be formatted correctly

Comment: Yes is useful for PHP but not for sorting in mysql .. i don't know a simple way for do this then i suggest you of normalize this data properly

Comment: The dots in `a.m.` and `p.m.` might be the problem, try to strip them like this : `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(bus_timing,'.',''), '%l:%i %p')`

Comment: even better: upper case your am and pm : `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(UCASE(bus_timing),'.',''), '%l:%i %p')`

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks, I've posted how it is sorted now

Comment: No, no, no. Start over, with a properly designed database.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why those `<br/>`'s got in there in the first place and why? Putting data on new lines can be achieved in the output.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yup, when I was inserting info, I didn't thought of sorting the info. So ...

Comment: You know that you can use REPLACE to get rid of those entirely if you wish; just be sure to work with a copy of that db if you want to go that route. It will simplify things.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks! I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `STR_TO_DATE` format and approach looks good. So the data might be the problem.

This

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(UCASE(bus_timing),'.',''), '%l:%i %p')
```

will remove the dots in `a.m.` and `p.m.` and change them to upper case, which will be more in line with the expected `%p` format

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. Would it be possible to remove everything after the `<br/>` part?

Comment: Wait... you have those <br/> in the database?? I thought it was just a formatting issue while copy/pasting here

Comment: I also see that you edited your question and changed how the data is displayed. For the bus B, when I asnwred you had one row for each time, and now everything is grouped together. Very confusing

Answer (score 1):

If you can format  the date this way 8 00 am instead  of 8 a.m.   you could use

```
select STR_TO_DATE( substr('8 30 am<br/>9 a.m. ', 1, 
              LOCATE('<br/>','8 30 am<br/>9 a.m. ') -1), '%l%i %p');
```

You should obtain the time only for the first value and sort for this

Answer (score 1):

Use `substring_index()` to break the string apart and get the first element.  Then sort by the first element.

So:

```
order by str_to_date(substring_index(time, '<', 1), '%l:%i %p')
```